# Can a function sometimes return something, sometimes not?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript functions always return a value, whether it is `undefined` or a specific value.

Let's consider this function:

```
function myFt(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 10) {
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

This function returns `true` when the array passed as an argument contains the value `10`, else it returns `undefined` since no return value is specified when reaching the end of the function.

I have learnt from my experience that it is often a good practice to make things the most explicit possible. Is it acceptable to write a JavaScript function that returns either a specific value or the default `undefined`? Or should I explicitly return a value no matter the issue?

Comment: `else it returns undefined`.....where?

Comment: ^^^ by design ...

Comment: @Jai I may be mistaken, but it seems to me that JavaScript returns `undefined` by default when the end of a function is reached.

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't understand your comment

Comment: @gentilpapillon She was replying to Jai saying that this behaviour is by design and doesn't need to be explicitly returned.

Comment: any function of javascript returns `undefined`, if not another value is returned. please have a look here: [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: in case you return true, returning false instead of undefined can help if you trully expect a boolean at the end. I have some experience in typed language and personnaly prefer returning a neutral value of the type (`''` for string, `0` for number...) instead of undefined, this way I don't have to check for undefined before using the return value

Comment: why not `array.includes(10)` ?

Comment: @JaxTeller the function I wrote is an example. In a real world project I would use the `includes` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to return nothing, not clear at all, but it is feasible..

If you return nothing, undefined will be returned by default. you can invoke your function like:

```
if(myFt(someData)){
    // you have returned something
}else{
    // you returned nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter, if you define explicitly return or not. It will always return `undefined`.

```js
let array = [1,2,10,5];
let array1 = [1,2,7,5];

function myFt(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 10) {
      return true
    }
  }
}

console.log(myFt(array));
console.log(myFt(array1));
```

Returned `undefine` value you can easily check with the following ways.

```
1. if(myFt(array)){...} else {...} // undefined will directly push to else.
2. if(myFt(array) == undefined)
3. if(typeof myFt(array) === 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an explicit [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) at the end of the function with `false` to prevent `undefined`, the default value which is returned at the end of any function of Javascript.

You may consiter to use the same type of return values, because if you use it to check a value in an array, you need a boolean value instead of a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)/[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value which is faster to check without conversion.

```
// returns either true or false, depending on a value of the array
function has10(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === 10) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you want but you need to check for return at the end, prefer returning a neutral value

```
// neutral values
let string = ""
let number = 0
```

Here's what can append if you return undefined without checking

```js
function noReturn() {} 

console.log(`1 + noReturn() = ${1 + noReturn()}`)
console.log(`1 + 0 = ${1 + 0}`)

console.log(`"string" + noReturn() = ${"string" + noReturn()}`)
console.log(`"string" + "" = ${"string" + ""}`)
```

as you can see some unexpected behavior can follow because you returned undefined

In case of boolean since `undefined` is a [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value that's no problem